# Re-arranging terms in Integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

**Is it ok if i write** $\int_{0}^\infty \frac { \ln {(1+x)}  }{ x^2 } $ **to** $\int_{0}^\infty \ { \ln {(1+x)}  }*{\frac{1} x^2 } $ **and then apply integration byparts rule?**

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Works in this case, but you need to be very careful in general. As you know, infinity is always prepared to fool you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to write it as
$$
\int\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}\,dx
=
\int\ln(1+x)\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx
$$
and then apply integration by parts, with $1/x^2$ as differential factor and $\ln(1+x)$ as finite factor, so
$$
\int\ln(1+x)\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx=\ln(1+x)\frac{-1}{x}-
\int\frac{1}{1+x}\frac{-1}{x}\,dx
$$
Now
$$
\frac{1}{x(1+x)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1+x}
$$
so the integral is
$$
\int\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}\,dx=-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}+\ln x-\ln(1+x)=
-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}+\ln\frac{x}{1+x}
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}+\ln\frac{x}{1+x}\right)=-\infty
$$
the integral is not convergent at $0$.

It is convergent at $\infty$, though, because
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}+\ln\frac{x}{1+x}\right)=0
$$

Thus, for instance,
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}\,dx=2\ln2
$$
but the integral over $(0,\infty)$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

your integral is divergent since

when $x \to 0^+$

$\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2} $ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{x}$

and

$\int_0\frac{dx}{x}$ is divergent.